# How to scale an image of javaFX from the center instead of top-left (ImageView)

Tags: javafx, imageview, fxml

I need to scale or zoom my image, but when I try to scale it, it always has centered in top-left. How can I scale from the center or any other places based on my preference?

Link on the full [project](https://github.com/danivichkin/demo_GIS)

```
@FXML
void plusButton(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    double height = ImageView.getFitHeight();
    double width = ImageView.getFitWidth();

    ImageView.setFitHeight(height + 100);
    ImageView.setFitWidth(width + 100);

    //TODO
    //Rectangle2D rectangle2D = new Rectangle2D(800, 800, 800, 800);
    //ImageView.setViewport(rectangle2D);
}
```

Comment: The `Node#scaleX` and `Node#scaleY` properties use the center as the pivot point. If you want more control over the pivot point then you can use a [`Scale`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/transform/Scale.html) transform, which can be added to a node via [`Node#getTransforms()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#getTransforms()).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you are changing the entire width and height of `ImageView`, which is the container of `Image`. In order to zoom or scale your images in `JavaFX` you need to work with `ViewPort` of `ImageView`s.

Whenever you zoom-in or zoom-out, it is necessary to set new `ViewPort`.

```
imageView.setViewport(new Rectangle2D(minX, minY, width, height));
```

According to [Oracle's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/geometry/Rectangle2D.html#Rectangle2D-double-double-double-double-):

> Parameters:
>
> `minX` - The x coordinate of the upper-left corner of the `Rectangle2D`
>
> `minY` - The y coordinate of the upper-left corner of the `Rectangle2D`
>
> `width` - The width of the `Rectangle2D`
>
> `height` - The height of the `Rectangle2D`

I did not debug your code, but the following code can be very helpful. Try to tweak it and learn the concept then it is far easier to apply changes to your code.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Hyperlink;
import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class PlutoExplorer extends Application {

    private static final String IMAGE_CREDIT_URL = "http://www.nasa.gov/image-feature/global-mosaic-of-pluto-in-true-color";
    private static final String IMAGE_URL = "https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/thumbnails/image/global-mosaic-of-pluto-in-true-color.jpg";

    private static final int MIN_PIXELS = 10;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Image image = new Image(IMAGE_URL);
        double width = image.getWidth();
        double height = image.getHeight();

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
        imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
        reset(imageView, width / 2, height / 2);

        ObjectProperty<Point2D> mouseDown = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

        imageView.setOnMousePressed(e -> {

            Point2D mousePress = imageViewToImage(imageView, new Point2D(e.getX(), e.getY()));
            mouseDown.set(mousePress);
        });

        imageView.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
            Point2D dragPoint = imageViewToImage(imageView, new Point2D(e.getX(), e.getY()));
            shift(imageView, dragPoint.subtract(mouseDown.get()));
            mouseDown.set(imageViewToImage(imageView, new Point2D(e.getX(), e.getY())));
        });

        imageView.setOnScroll(e -> {
            double delta = e.getDeltaY();
            Rectangle2D viewport = imageView.getViewport();

            double scale = clamp(Math.pow(1.01, delta),

                // don't scale so we're zoomed in to fewer than MIN_PIXELS in any direction:
                Math.min(MIN_PIXELS / viewport.getWidth(), MIN_PIXELS / viewport.getHeight()),

                // don't scale so that we're bigger than image dimensions:
                Math.max(width / viewport.getWidth(), height / viewport.getHeight())

            );

            Point2D mouse = imageViewToImage(imageView, new Point2D(e.getX(), e.getY()));

            double newWidth = viewport.getWidth() * scale;
            double newHeight = viewport.getHeight() * scale;

            // To keep the visual point under the mouse from moving, we need
            // (x - newViewportMinX) / (x - currentViewportMinX) = scale
            // where x is the mouse X coordinate in the image

            // solving this for newViewportMinX gives

            // newViewportMinX = x - (x - currentViewportMinX) * scale 

            // we then clamp this value so the image never scrolls out
            // of the imageview:

            double newMinX = clamp(mouse.getX() - (mouse.getX() - viewport.getMinX()) * scale, 
                    0, width - newWidth);
            double newMinY = clamp(mouse.getY() - (mouse.getY() - viewport.getMinY()) * scale, 
                    0, height - newHeight);

            imageView.setViewport(new Rectangle2D(newMinX, newMinY, newWidth, newHeight));
        });

            imageView.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
                if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
                reset(imageView, width, height);
            }
        });

        Hyperlink link = new Hyperlink("Image Credit: NASA/JHUAPL/SwRI");
        link.setOnAction(e -> getHostServices().showDocument(IMAGE_CREDIT_URL));

        link.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        link.setTooltip(new Tooltip(IMAGE_CREDIT_URL));

        HBox buttons = createButtons(width, height, imageView);
        Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip("Scroll to zoom, drag to pan");
        Tooltip.install(buttons, tooltip);

        Pane container = new Pane(imageView);
        container.setPrefSize(800, 600);

        imageView.fitWidthProperty().bind(container.widthProperty());
        imageView.fitHeightProperty().bind(container.heightProperty());
        VBox root = new VBox(link, container, buttons);
        root.setFillWidth(true);
        VBox.setVgrow(container, Priority.ALWAYS);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Pluto explorer");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private HBox createButtons(double width, double height, ImageView imageView) {
        Button reset = new Button("Reset");
        reset.setOnAction(e -> reset(imageView, width / 2, height / 2));
        Button full = new Button("Full view");
        full.setOnAction(e -> reset(imageView, width, height));
        HBox buttons = new HBox(10, reset, full);
        buttons.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        buttons.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        return buttons;
    }

    // reset to the top left:
    private void reset(ImageView imageView, double width, double height) {
        imageView.setViewport(new Rectangle2D(0, 0, width, height));
    }

    // shift the viewport of the imageView by the specified delta, clamping so
    // the viewport does not move off the actual image:
    private void shift(ImageView imageView, Point2D delta) {
        Rectangle2D viewport = imageView.getViewport();

        double width = imageView.getImage().getWidth() ;
        double height = imageView.getImage().getHeight() ;

        double maxX = width - viewport.getWidth();
        double maxY = height - viewport.getHeight();

        double minX = clamp(viewport.getMinX() - delta.getX(), 0, maxX);
        double minY = clamp(viewport.getMinY() - delta.getY(), 0, maxY);

        imageView.setViewport(new Rectangle2D(minX, minY, viewport.getWidth(), viewport.getHeight()));
    }

    private double clamp(double value, double min, double max) {

        if (value < min)
            return min;
        if (value > max)
            return max;
        return value;
    }

    // convert mouse coordinates in the imageView to coordinates in the actual image:
    private Point2D imageViewToImage(ImageView imageView, Point2D imageViewCoordinates) {
        double xProportion = imageViewCoordinates.getX() / imageView.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth();
        double yProportion = imageViewCoordinates.getY() / imageView.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight();

        Rectangle2D viewport = imageView.getViewport();
        return new Point2D(
                viewport.getMinX() + xProportion * viewport.getWidth(), 
                viewport.getMinY() + yProportion * viewport.getHeight());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The above-mentioned code is imported from [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/james-d/ce5ec1fd44ce6c64e81a).

Comment: The question does not sound like showing part of the image is the desired result. Instead the desired outcome seems to be scaling the image with a different pivot point...

Answer (score 0):

This is a rewrite of the previously posted PlutoExplorer example.

I've separated the GUI from the Controller logic somewhat, altogether tried to add more structure to the code, and added some rudimentary Rotation logic.

Exhaustive Javadoc & Comments have been added throughout.

I found the Mouse Zoom direction in the original counter-intuitive, so I've reversed the direction.
(If you prefer, the direction can now be changed by a simple modification to the Zoom enum)

There was also a very small Bug in the original (well, superfluous code in the Drag logic) which has been removed.

This was the superfluous line in the Drag logic:

```
mouseDown.set(imageViewToImage(imageView, new Point2D(e.getX(), e.getY())));
```

This new version was written using the Zulu OpenJDK 17 JavaFX Bundle. I've tried not to use too many new features, so it should work on earlier JDK's.

[PlutoExplorerExtended.java can be found here.](https://gist.github.com/DanskerDave/7ea13c6f3387bf3fbb5a09af07922ac2)
The source is also included inline below.

Thank you very much to whoever wrote the original, it was a massive help.

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.*;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.image.*;
import javafx.scene.input.ScrollEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

/**
 * A JavaFX Demo of Image Zoom, Drag & Rotation.
 */
public final class PlutoExplorerExtended extends Application {

    private static final double       HALF   = 0.5d;
    /**
     * This is the number of Zoom-In operations required to
     * <b><i>almost exactly</i></b>
     * halve the size of the Viewport.
     */
    private static final int          ZOOM_N = 9; // TODO try.: 1 <= ZOOM_N <= 20"-ish"
    /**
     * This factor guarantees that after
     * {@link  #ZOOM_N}
     * times Zoom-In, the Viewport-size halves
     * <b><i>almost exactly</i></b>.<br>
     * (HALF was chosen to - perhaps? - avoid excessive Image degradation when zooming)<br>
     * For ZOOM_N = 9 the factor value is approximately 93%
     */
    private static final double       ZOOM_IN_SCALE = Math.pow(HALF, 1.0d / ZOOM_N);

    /**
     * Enumeration of the possible Zoom actions.
     */
    private static enum  Zoom {
        /**
         * If Shift was pressed while
         * Scrolling, the action
         * will be ignored         */ ZOOM_NONE( 0, Double.NaN),
        /** = Mouse Scroll Up      */ ZOOM_IN  ( 1,        ZOOM_IN_SCALE),
        /** = Mouse Scroll Down    */ ZOOM_OUT (-1, 1.0d / ZOOM_IN_SCALE);

        /** 0, 1 or -1  */ private final int    zoomLevelDelta;
        /** Zoom-Factor */ private final double scale;

        private Zoom(final int zoomLevelDelta, final double scale) {
            this.zoomLevelDelta = zoomLevelDelta;
            this.scale          = scale;
        }
        private static Zoom of(final ScrollEvent scrollEvent) {

            final double scrollAmount = scrollEvent.getDeltaY();

            if (scrollAmount == 0) {
                return ZOOM_NONE;
            }
            if (scrollAmount >  0) {
                return ZOOM_IN;
            } else {
                return ZOOM_OUT;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @see ZoomDragPane#ZoomDragPane(Image, double, double)
     */
    private static final class ZoomDragPane extends Pane {

        private static final double      MIN_PX    = 10;

        private              int         zoomLevel = 0;
        private        final ImageView   view;
        private        final double      imageWidth;
        private        final double      imageHeight;
        private        final double      rotation90scale;

        /**
         * Create a
         * {@link  Pane}
         * container for an
         * {@link  ImageView}
         * which encapsulates all the Zoom, Drag & Rotation logic for an Image.
         * 
         * @param image       the Image to be displayed
         * @param prefWidth   the desired width  of the Pane
         * @param prefHeight  the desired height of the Pane
         */
        private ZoomDragPane(final Image image, final double prefWidth, final double prefHeight) {

            this.setPrefSize(prefWidth, prefHeight);
            this.setStyle   ("-fx-background-color: LIGHTGREY");

            this.view = new ImageView(image);
            this.view.setPreserveRatio(true);
            this.view.setSmooth       (true);
            this.view.setCache        (true);

            this.getChildren().add(this.view);

            this.imageWidth      = image.getWidth();
            this.imageHeight     = image.getHeight();

            this.view.setViewport(new Rectangle2D(0, 0, this.imageWidth, this.imageHeight));

            /*
             * Unless its square, the Image must be scaled when rotated through 90 (or 270) degrees...
             */
            this.rotation90scale = Math.min(this.imageWidth, this.imageHeight) / Math.max(this.imageWidth, this.imageHeight);

            this.view.fitWidthProperty() .bind(this.widthProperty());
            this.view.fitHeightProperty().bind(this.heightProperty());

            setMouseDraggedEventHandler();

            this.view.setOnScroll(e -> zoom(e));
        }

        /**
         * Drag the Viewport as the Mouse is moved.
         */
        private void setMouseDraggedEventHandler() {

            final ObjectProperty<Point2D>    mouseDown = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
            /*
             * Remember where the Mouse was in the Image when it was pressed...
             */
            this.view.setOnMousePressed(e -> mouseDown.set(imageViewToImage(e.getX(), e.getY())));
            /*
             * Using the above, work out how far the Mouse has been dragged & adjust the Viewport...
             */
            this.view.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
                final Point2D     dragPoint = imageViewToImage(e.getX(), e.getY());
                final Point2D     dragDelta = dragPoint.subtract(mouseDown.get());

                final Rectangle2D viewport  = this.view.getViewport();

                final double      newX      = viewport.getMinX() - dragDelta.getX();
                final double      newY      = viewport.getMinY() - dragDelta.getY();

                setImageViewport(newX, newY, viewport.getWidth(), viewport.getHeight());
            });
        }

        /**
         * Zoom Event-Handler. Zooms In or Out exactly 1 Level (if at all).
         * <p>
         * Note.: the X-/Y-Coordinates returned by the ScrollEvent are relative-to-the-ImageView
         * and need to be normalised to relative-to-the-Image for the Zoom & Viewport calculations.
         * 
         * @param scrollEvent
         */
        private void zoom(final ScrollEvent scrollEvent) {

            final Zoom zoom          = Zoom.of(scrollEvent);
            final int  zoomLevelTry  = this.zoomLevel + zoom.zoomLevelDelta;
            /*
             * Zoomed out too far or no Zoom at all? Then there's nothing to do...
             */
            if (zoomLevelTry < 0
            ||  zoom == Zoom.ZOOM_NONE) {
                return;
            }
            /*
             * Calculate the Viewport Size for the desired Zoom-Level...
             */
            final Dimension2D newSize = zoomCalculateViewportSize(zoomLevelTry);
            /*
             * If the maximum Zoom-Level has been exceeded there's nothing to do...
             */
            if (Math.min(newSize.getWidth(), newSize.getHeight()) < MIN_PX) {
                return;
            }
            /* --------------------------------------------------------------
             * 
             * OK, the new Zoom-Level is valid:
             * -> calculate the new Viewport X-/Y-coordinates & update the Viewport...
             * (we Zoom in or out centred around the Pixel at the Mouse position) 
             */
            this.zoomLevel = zoomLevelTry;

            final Point2D mouseInImage = imageViewToImage(scrollEvent.getX(), scrollEvent.getY());

            final Point2D newLocation  = zoomCalculateNewViewportXY(mouseInImage, zoom.scale);
            /*
             * Store the new Coordinates & Size in the Viewport...
             */
            setImageViewport(newLocation.getX(), newLocation.getY(), newSize.getWidth(), newSize.getHeight());
        }

        /**
         * To fix the Pixel @ the Mouse X-coordinate, the following is true:
         * <br>
         * {@code  (x - newViewportMinX) / (x - currentViewportMinX) = scale}
         * <p>
         * The new Viewport X-coordinate is therefore given by:
         * <br>
         * {@code  newViewportMinX = x - (x - currentViewportMinX) * scale}
         * <p>
         * The new Viewport Y-coordinate is calculated similarly.
         * 
         * @param imageMouse  the Mouse coordinates relative to the Image
         * @param scale       the Zoom-factor
         * @return            X-/Y-coordinate of the new Viewport<br>
         * (which
         * {@link  #setImageViewport(double, double, double, double)}
         * will bring into Range if necessary)
         */
        private Point2D zoomCalculateNewViewportXY(final Point2D imageMouse, final double scale) {

            final Rectangle2D oldViewport = this.view.getViewport();

            final double      mouseX      = imageMouse.getX();
            final double      mouseY      = imageMouse.getY();

            final double      newX        = mouseX - (mouseX - oldViewport.getMinX()) * scale;
            final double      newY        = mouseY - (mouseY - oldViewport.getMinY()) * scale;

            return new Point2D(newX, newY);
        }

        /**
         * Calculate the Viewport size for a particular
         * {@code  zoomLevel}.
         * 
         * @param  zoomLevel  the Zoom Level
         * @return
         */
        private Dimension2D zoomCalculateViewportSize(final int zoomLevel) {

            final double zoomScale = Math.pow(ZOOM_IN_SCALE, zoomLevel);

            final double newWidth  = this.imageWidth  * zoomScale;
            final double newHeight = this.imageHeight * zoomScale;

            return new Dimension2D(newWidth, newHeight);
        }

        /**
         * Zoom in to the requested
         * {@code  zoomLevel}.<br>
         * (the Viewport will be centred within the Image)
         * 
         * @param zoomLevel
         */
        private void zoomInCentredToLevel(final int zoomLevel) {

            this.zoomLevel = zoomLevel;
            /*
             * Calculate the Viewport Size for the desired Zoom-Level...
             */
            final Dimension2D newSize = zoomCalculateViewportSize(zoomLevel);

            final double      newX    = (this.imageWidth  -  newSize.getWidth() ) / 2;
            final double      newY    = (this.imageHeight -  newSize.getHeight()) / 2;

            setImageViewport(newX, newY, newSize.getWidth(), newSize.getHeight());
        }

        /**
         * Calculate Mouse coordinates within the Image based on coordinates within the ImageView.
         * 
         * @param viewX  X-coordinate of the Mouse within the ImageView
         * @param viewY  Y-coordinate of the Mouse within the ImageView
         * 
         * @return       Coordinates of the Mouse within the Image
         */
        private Point2D imageViewToImage(final double viewX, final double viewY) {

            final Bounds      boundsLocal = this.view.getBoundsInLocal();

            final double      xProportion = viewX / boundsLocal.getWidth();
            final double      yProportion = viewY / boundsLocal.getHeight();

            final Rectangle2D viewport    = this.view.getViewport();

            final double      imageX      = viewport.getMinX() + xProportion * viewport.getWidth();
            final double      imageY      = viewport.getMinY() + yProportion * viewport.getHeight();

            return new Point2D(imageX, imageY);
        }

        /**
         * Store the new Coordinates & Size in the Viewport.<br>
         * (making sure that the Viewport remains within the Image)
         * 
         * @param x
         * @param y
         * @param width
         * @param height
         * 
         * @see  ImageView#setViewport(Rectangle2D)
         */
        private void setImageViewport(final double x, final double y, final double width, final double height) {

            final double xMax   = this.imageWidth  - width;
            final double yMax   = this.imageHeight - height;

            final double xClamp = Math.max(0, Math.min(x, xMax)); // 0 <= x <= xMax
            final double yClamp = Math.max(0, Math.min(y, yMax)); // 0 <= y <= yMax

            this.view.setViewport(new Rectangle2D(xClamp, yClamp, width, height));
        }

        /**
         * The Image will either be rotated or the rotation will be reset to zero.
         * <p>
         * Note:
         * this rotation logic was conceived for multiples of 90 degrees.<br>
         * It can, however, handle any angle, but the rotation90scale logic would need a touch of Pythagoras.
         * 
         * @param relativeRotation  the rotation angle, in Degrees (0 = reset to zero)<br>
         */
        private void rotateOrReset(final double relativeRotation) {

            final double rotatePrevious = this.view.getRotate();

            if (relativeRotation == 0) {
                if (rotatePrevious != 0) {
                    rotateAndScale(rotatePrevious, 0);
                }
            } else {
                rotateAndScale    (rotatePrevious, rotatePrevious + relativeRotation);
            }
        }
        private void rotateAndScale(final double previousRotation, final double absoluteRotation) {

            this.view.setRotate(absoluteRotation);

            if (this.imageWidth == this.imageHeight) {
                return;
            }

            final boolean multiple180previous = previousRotation % 180 == 0;
            final boolean multiple180new      = absoluteRotation % 180 == 0;

            if (multiple180new == multiple180previous) {
                return;
            }
            if (multiple180new) {
                this.view.setScaleX(1.0d);
                this.view.setScaleY(1.0d);
            } else {
                this.view.setScaleX(rotation90scale);
                this.view.setScaleY(rotation90scale);
            }
        }
    }

    private static final String TITLE            = "Pluto Explorer";
    private static final String IMAGE_CREDIT_URL = "http://www.nasa.gov/image-feature/global-mosaic-of-pluto-in-true-color";
    private static final String IMAGE_URL        = "https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/thumbnails/image/global-mosaic-of-pluto-in-true-color.jpg";

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) {

        final Image        image     = new Image(IMAGE_URL);
        final double       paneWidth = image.getWidth();

        final ZoomDragPane pane      = new ZoomDragPane(image, paneWidth, paneWidth * image.getHeight() / image.getWidth());

        final Hyperlink    link      = new Hyperlink("Image Credit: NASA/JHUAPL/SwRI");
        ;                  link.setOnAction(e -> getHostServices().showDocument(IMAGE_CREDIT_URL));
        ;                  link.setPadding (new Insets(10));
        ;                  link.setTooltip (new Tooltip(IMAGE_CREDIT_URL));

        final HBox         buttons   = createButtons(pane);

        final VBox         root      = new VBox(link, pane, buttons);
        ;                  root.setFillWidth(true);

        VBox.setVgrow(pane, Priority.ALWAYS);

        installTooltip(pane);

        pane.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
                final Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
                ;           alert.setTitle      (TITLE);
                ;           alert.setHeaderText ("Double-Click Dialogue");
                ;           alert.setContentText("Press OK or Enter/Return");
                ;           alert.showAndWait();
            }
        });

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.setTitle(TITLE);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * Installs a once-only Tooltip centred over the Image.
     * 
     * @param zoomDragPane
     */
    private static void installTooltip(final ZoomDragPane zoomDragPane) {
        /*
         * Implementation note.:
         * hijacking the setOnShowing(...) method & performing a show(...) there
         * seems to be the only way of accurately positioning a Tooltip.
         * Even though the Tooltip is only displayed once, the setOnShowing(...) method
         * is invoked 3 times, each time with a different Tooltip size,
         * the last of which seems to be final & is (apart from the 18 Pixel discrepancy) correct.
         */
        final Tooltip toolTip = new Tooltip("Scroll to zoom, drag to pan");
        ;             toolTip.setOpacity     (0.75);
        ;             toolTip.setShowDelay   (Duration.seconds(0.5));
        ;             toolTip.setShowDuration(Duration.seconds(9));
        ;             toolTip.setOnShown     (e -> Tooltip.uninstall(zoomDragPane, toolTip));
        ;             toolTip.setOnShowing   (e -> {
            final Node   view            = zoomDragPane.view;
            final Bounds viewBoundsLocal = view.getBoundsInLocal();
            final Bounds viewBounds      = view.localToScreen(viewBoundsLocal);

            final int    toolTipFudge    = 18; // Fudge because Tooltip claims to be larger than it really is

            final double toolTipWidth    = toolTip.getWidth()  - toolTipFudge;
            final double toolTipHeight   = toolTip.getHeight() - toolTipFudge;

            final double toolTipOffsetX  = (viewBounds.getWidth()  - toolTipWidth ) / 2;
            final double toolTipOffsetY  = (viewBounds.getHeight() - toolTipHeight) / 2;

            toolTip.show(zoomDragPane, viewBounds.getMinX() + toolTipOffsetX, viewBounds.getMinY() + toolTipOffsetY);
        });
        Tooltip.install (zoomDragPane, toolTip);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a Bar with Zoom Buttons & Rotation CheckBox.
     * 
     * @param zoomDragPane
     * @return
     */
    private static HBox createButtons(final ZoomDragPane zoomDragPane) {

        final char      DEGREE  = '\u00B0';

        final CheckBox  rotate  = new CheckBox("Rotate 90" + DEGREE + " (Toggle)");
        ;               rotate.setOnAction(e -> zoomDragPane.rotateOrReset(rotate.isSelected() ? 90 : 0));
        ;               rotate.setPadding(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 50));

        final HBox      toolBox = new HBox(10);
        ;               toolBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        ;               toolBox.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        IntStream.range(0, 3).forEach(n -> {
            final Button              zoom      = new Button("Zoom " + ((int) Math.pow(2, n)) + "00%");
            ;                         zoom.setOnAction(e -> zoomDragPane.zoomInCentredToLevel(ZOOM_N * n));
            toolBox.getChildren().add(zoom);
        });
        toolBox    .getChildren().add(rotate);

        return toolBox;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```