JavaFX Zooming remain children relative node position
I am trying to build a zoomable and pannable 2D map for a video game.
The map consists of an image view for the background image and a Group container that contains my child nodes. In my setting the child nodes are castle components which each have an image view, and a label.
I have heavily been inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/72657643/25394920
The panning and zooming works great however when zooming I can't get the nodes in my Group to remain at the relative same position
The zooming and panning works by modifying the viewport of the background image view.
This is my current class:
public class ZoomDragComponent extends Pane {
    @FXML
    ImageView view;

    //...

    private DoubleProperty imageWidth;
    private DoubleProperty imageHeight;
    private DoubleProperty zoomLevel;
    private Zoom currentZoom;
    private Group castleContainer;


    private enum Zoom {

        ZOOM_NONE(0, Double.NaN),
        ZOOM_IN(1, ZOOM_IN_SCALE),
        ZOOM_OUT(-1, 1.0d / ZOOM_IN_SCALE);

        private final int zoomLevelDelta;
        private final double scale;

        Zoom(final int zoomLevelDelta, final double scale) {
            this.zoomLevelDelta = zoomLevelDelta;
            this.scale = scale;
        }

        private static Zoom of(final ScrollEvent scrollEvent) {
            final double scrollAmount = scrollEvent.getDeltaY();

            if (scrollAmount == 0) {
                return ZOOM_NONE;
            }

            if (scrollAmount > 0) {
                return ZOOM_IN;
            }

            return ZOOM_OUT;
        }
    }

    @Inject
    public ZoomDragComponent() {
    }

    @OnRender
    public void OnRender() {
        this.zoomLevel = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);
        this.castleContainer = new Group();
        this.getChildren().add(castleContainer);

        Image image = this.imageCache.get("image/ingame_background.png", INGAME_BACKGROUND_WIDTH, INGAME_BACKGROUND_HEIGHT);
        this.view.setImage(image);
        this.view.setCache(true);
        this.view.setSmooth(true);

        this.imageWidth = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        this.imageHeight = new SimpleDoubleProperty();

        this.imageWidth.bind(image.widthProperty());
        this.imageHeight.bind(image.heightProperty());

        this.view.setViewport(new Rectangle2D(0, 0, INGAME_BACKGROUND_WIDTH, INGAME_BACKGROUND_HEIGHT));

        this.view.fitWidthProperty().bind(this.widthProperty());
        this.view.fitHeightProperty().bind(this.heightProperty());

        final ObjectProperty<Point2D> mouseDown = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

        //save mouse position on drag start to calculate the drag difference
        this.setOnMousePressed(e -> mouseDown.set(imageViewToImage(e.getX(), e.getY())));

        //calculate the drag difference and move the viewport accordingly
        this.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
            final Point2D dragPoint = imageViewToImage(e.getX(), e.getY());
            final Point2D dragDelta = dragPoint.subtract(mouseDown.get());

            final Rectangle2D viewport = this.view.getViewport();

            final double newX = viewport.getMinX() - dragDelta.getX();
            final double newY = viewport.getMinY() - dragDelta.getY();

            setImageViewport(newX, newY, viewport.getWidth(), viewport.getHeight());
        });

        this.setOnScroll(this::handleScroll);
    }

    private void setImageViewport(double newX, double newY, double width, double height) {
        final double xMax = this.imageWidth.get() - width;
        final double yMax = this.imageHeight.get() - height;

        //clamp to image size
        final double xClamp = Math.max(0, Math.min(newX, xMax)); // 0 <= newX <= xMax
        final double yClamp = Math.max(0, Math.min(newY, yMax)); // 0 <= newY <= yMax

        this.view.setViewport(new Rectangle2D(xClamp, yClamp, width, height));
    }

    //mouse coordinates in image view to image coordinates
    private Point2D imageViewToImage(double viewX, double viewY) {
        final Bounds boundsLocal = this.view.getBoundsInLocal();

        final double      xProportion = viewX / boundsLocal.getWidth();
        final double      yProportion = viewY / boundsLocal.getHeight();

        final Rectangle2D viewport    = this.view.getViewport();

        final double      imageX      = viewport.getMinX() + xProportion * viewport.getWidth();
        final double      imageY      = viewport.getMinY() + yProportion * viewport.getHeight();

        return new Point2D(imageX, imageY);
    }

    private void handleScroll(ScrollEvent scrollEvent) {
        this.currentZoom          = Zoom.of(scrollEvent);

        final int  zoomLevelTry  = (int) (this.zoomLevel.get() + this.currentZoom.zoomLevelDelta);
        if ( zoomLevelTry < 0 || this.currentZoom == Zoom.ZOOM_NONE ) {
            return;
        }

        final Dimension2D newSize = zoomCalculateViewportSize(zoomLevelTry);
        if ( Math.min(newSize.getWidth(), newSize.getHeight()) < MIN_PX ) {
            return;
        }

        this.zoomLevel.set(zoomLevelTry);

        final Point2D mouseInImage = imageViewToImage(scrollEvent.getX(), scrollEvent.getY());
        final Point2D newLocation  = zoomCalculateNewViewportXY(mouseInImage, this.currentZoom.scale);

        setImageViewport(newLocation.getX(), newLocation.getY(), newSize.getWidth(), newSize.getHeight());
    }

    private Point2D zoomCalculateNewViewportXY(final Point2D imageMouse, final double scale) {
        final Rectangle2D oldViewport = this.view.getViewport();

        final double      mouseX      = imageMouse.getX();
        final double      mouseY      = imageMouse.getY();

        final double      newX        = mouseX - (mouseX - oldViewport.getMinX()) * scale;
        final double      newY        = mouseY - (mouseY - oldViewport.getMinY()) * scale;

        return new Point2D(newX, newY);
    }

    private Dimension2D zoomCalculateViewportSize(final int zoomLevel) {
        final double zoomScale = Math.pow(ZOOM_IN_SCALE, zoomLevel);

        final double newWidth  = this.imageWidth.get()  * zoomScale;
        final double newHeight = this.imageHeight.get() * zoomScale;

        return new Dimension2D(newWidth, newHeight);
    }

    public void addImageRelativeNode(Node node, double imgX, double imgY) {
        DoubleProperty layoutX = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        DoubleProperty layoutY = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        DoubleProperty paneScaleX = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        DoubleProperty paneScaleY = new SimpleDoubleProperty();

        // 0,0 starts at the center of the map
        final double centerWidth = INGAME_BACKGROUND_WIDTH / 2.0;
        final double centerHeight = INGAME_BACKGROUND_HEIGHT / 2.0;

        imgX = Math.min(INGAME_BACKGROUND_WIDTH, (imgX * 10) + centerWidth);
        imgY = Math.min(INGAME_BACKGROUND_WIDTH, (imgY * 10) + centerHeight);

        // bind properties to ImageView coordinates (panning)
        final double finalImgX = imgX;
        layoutX.bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(
                () -> imageToViewX(finalImgX),
                this.view.viewportProperty(), //listen on viewport change
                this.widthProperty() //listen on window width change
        ));

        final double finalImgY = imgY;
        layoutY.bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(
                () -> imageToViewY(finalImgY),
                this.view.viewportProperty(), //listen on viewport change
                this.heightProperty() //listen on window height change
        ));

        paneScaleX.bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(
                () -> 1.0 / Math.pow(ZOOM_IN_SCALE, zoomLevel.get()),
                this.zoomLevel
        ));

        paneScaleY.bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(
                () -> 1.0 / Math.pow(ZOOM_IN_SCALE, zoomLevel.get()),
                this.zoomLevel
        ));
        node.scaleXProperty().bind(paneScaleX);
        node.scaleYProperty().bind(paneScaleY);

        node.layoutXProperty().bind(layoutX);
        node.layoutYProperty().bind(layoutY);
    }

    // translate view coordinates to image coordinates
    public double imageToViewX(double imgX) {
        Rectangle2D viewport = view.getViewport();
        double viewportWidth = viewport.getWidth();
        double viewportX = viewport.getMinX();
        return (imgX - viewportX) * (view.getFitWidth() / viewportWidth);
    }

    public double imageToViewY(double imgY) {
        Rectangle2D viewport = view.getViewport();
        double viewportHeight = viewport.getHeight();
        double viewportY = viewport.getMinY();
        return (imgY - viewportY) * (view.getFitHeight() / viewportHeight);
    }
}

I am creating the nodes in another controller and they will be added to the Group container. Also addImageRelativeNode will be called with the local coordinates which will be translated to image coordinates in imageToViewX and imageToViewY
Showcase of the problem
I tried adding bindings to update the children layout properties whenever the viewport is changed. This works perfectly for panning but my logic lacks the support for zooming because the viewport size also changes on top of the new coordinates

If your Nodes are in the same container as the background image, then they are going to zoom too.  I think you need three Panes.  One for the background, one to hold the Nodes and then a StackPane to put the other two Panes in.  Then just zoom/scroll the background and recalculate the x/y of the Nodes based on the co-ordinates of the background in the ViewPort.

@DaveB thanks for your answer, i tried your solution out and it didn't solve the issue. here is the structure, the ZoomDragComponent is a StackPane and the CastleComponent is a VBox.
I think the issue lies in imageToViewX/Y which get called every-time the viewport property gets changed which I created to keep the nodes relative to the zoom point at the same place visually. It works for panning but for zooming it does not.
